# How to get yii2 registered assets list for creating SPF.js response array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I need getting list of yii2 assets registered in the page for creating an array for response SPF.js requests
I use this code in a new layout named ajax.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use app\assets\AppAsset;
use \yii\helpers\Json;

AppAsset::register($this);
$spf_data = [
    'title' => Html::encode($this->title),
    'head' => $this->beginPage() . Html::csrfMetaTags() . $this->head(),
    'body' => ['content' => $this->beginBody() . $content],
    "attr" => [
        'content' => [
            "class" => "container"
        ]
    ],
    'foot' => $this->endBody() . $this->endPage(),
];
echo Json::htmlEncode($spf_data);
```

my problem is registered assets to page and i can't get them in my array

i need to get list of meta tags,link tags and script in head index of array

how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get scripts and styles in your controller action with this code

```
ob_start();
ob_implicit_flush(false);
$this->view->beginPage();
$this->view->head();
$this->view->beginBody();
$this->renderPartial($view, $params);
$this->view->endBody();
$this->view->endPage(true);
$style_script= ob_get_clean();
```

and use `$style_script` in `$spf_data`

```
$spf_data = [
    'title' => Html::encode($this->title),
    'head' => $style_script,
    'body' => ['content' => $this->renderPartial('viewName')],
    "attr" => [
        'content' => [
            "class" => "container"
        ]
    ],
];
```

this code work for me